# using JSON in java

Tags: java, json

I want to use JSON in my client server application.

I need to send to the server the client name and subscribe or unsubscribe.

I'm new to java and very new to JSON.

Can I please get an example of how to do such a thing?

How can I encode the data using JSON on the client side, send it through UDP and decode it on the server side?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/ankurtrapasiya/JSONTest Just a sample application you can try.

Answer (score 2):

Use a third party library like XStream. It's very easy API to use.

Answer (score 1):

Take [mkyong's Jersey + Jackson example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/), or any other Jersey + Jackson example.

You'll need to familiarize yourself with with Java application server too though.

Answer (score 1):

[Google's GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is very easy to use and well-documented if you are new to this stuff. That will take care of the encoding / decoding for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SpringMVC will help you. See [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/).

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a framework that may help you. Please check https://sites.google.com/site/javacornproject/corn-gate project page to get detailed information.

Below is a sample code to define and implement a service in Gate:

```
@GateService(name="HelloWorldService",componentTarget="net.sf.corn.gate.sample.service.HelloWorldServiceImpl")
public interface IHelloWorldService {
   public String sayHelloWorld();
}

public class HelloWorldServiceImpl {
    public String sayHelloWorld(){
        return "Hello World";
    } 
}
```

Below are the couple of samples to access to  HelloWorldService from various clients :

1- JavaScript Client AJAX Call:

```
var jsonrq = new JsonRpcRequest("http://localhost:8888/jsonrpc");
var response = jsonrq.send("358", "HelloWorldService", "sayHelloWorld");
```

2-Java Remote Client:

```
JsonRpcClient client= new JsonRpcClient(new URI("http://localhost/jsonrpc"));
JsonRpcResponse resp= client.callAService("HelloWorldService","sayHelloWorld");
```

3-REST client (Browser)

```
http://localhost:8888/jsonrpc/HelloWorldService/sayHelloWorld
```

I hope this helps.